# How to constrain a query for number of items in ObjectStorage property in Extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I want to build queries in my Extbase repository that can filter out objects with a certain number of `items`. `items` is of type `ObjectStorage` in the model.

I tried to get objects with at least 1 item in this query, but it obviously doesn't work because the method "greater than" won't count the items in the objectStorage.

```
$x = 0; //any number
$query = $this->createQuery();
$constraints[] = $query->equals('deleted', 0);
$constraints[] = $query->equals('hidden', 0);
$constraints[] = $query->greaterThan('items', $x);
return $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints))->execute();
```

So how can I do this?
I was thinking about an SQL Statement, but how could I add it to constraints?
I don't want to do everything with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create yourself a custom constraint that does this. Have a look at how it is done in the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Qom\QueryObjectModelFactory`.

Comment: I looked into that `QueryObjectModelFactory.php` but I still have no idea how to create my own custom constraint - I think I would need an easy example in order to understand how to use that.

Comment: Well, you need to write an own class that implements the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Qom\ConstraintInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could do it without either using `$query->statement` or iterating the whole result without the "count" constraint and then throwing away the records with items lower than `$x`. (Apart from pgampe's approach that was posted at the exact same time.)

Which approach you take depends on performance considerations. If you have a small result set, doing a `foreach` on the QueryResult wouldn't hurt so much. But since every result is converted into an object in the process, you'll have a big overhead by doing so when you have a lot of records.

Keep in mind that using `$query->statement` won't make you lose the ability to work with the records as domain objects. So it's not a big deal to go this way.

Comment: What I actually don't know is how I can put all constraints together? Like `$query->equals('hidden', 0);`, etc. can I just put a `query->statement` into the `logicalAnd`in the end?

Comment: Nope. You have to write the whole SQL statement and then just createQuery()->statement()->execute()